# How to use google embed pdf viewer in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I tried this

```
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
<iframe src="{{ asset('jurnal/' . $journal->file) }}&embedded=true" style="width:90%; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Shows me error : NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Anyone can help please, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to link to Google's viewer, not just your file...

```
<iframe 
    src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url={{ asset('jurnal/' . $journal->file)     }}&embedded=true" 
    style="width:600px; height:500px;" 
    frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Also it looks like the link you are returning isn't a good link to the PDF file.  If you go to that page in a browser, it shouldn't show you a `NotFoundHttpException`

Comment: Because it's showing you the error `NotFoundHttpException` which means there isn't a file there and also Laravel doesn't know what to do with it.